# Accessing PulseAudio from Python script running as root

Tags: sound, python, pulseaudio, alsa

I want to run my Python script as root and communicate with PulseAudio using the Python3 pulsectl library (https://github.com/mk-fg/python-pulse-control). PulseAudio is not installed system-wide, only on a user level. I want to avoid having to install it system-wide.

Python script:

```
import pulsectl

pulse = pulsectl.Pulse()
```

Result:

```
Failed to connect to pulseaudio server.
```

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 lts

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 will reach end of life on January 20, 2022. Sorry it is now of topic on this site.